# Why answers are being deleted by moderator?

Tags: discussion, support

So recently I answered this question: [What was Madhvacharya's argument against the Shaktas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9471/647) which was asked by one of our Moderator. I am sure I didn't receive enough flag for my answer, but this Mod deleted my answer, Ref: Screenshot.

[image]

My answer link: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27077/647

There was one more answer to this question, He deleted that as well. 
My doubt is, why he himself deleting answers on post, why he just doesn't wait for enough flags ? Why he doesn't respect SE community tools and rules? Why he is making all decisions on his own ? 
Just because he is a moderator, He should abuse his privileges ?

Comment: **Deletion of answers is highly inconsistent in this site**. There are no objective rules. Our answers are on moderators' mercy. I had at least 6 answers deleted in past which matched the criteria of answering! Sometimes they put banners, sometimes they don't & sometimes delete. Lots of discussion in past. I would advise you to start your answer with following: "*There are no arguments provided by Madhavacharya or his followers on this aspect*". That will objectively make you answering the Qn. Then flag it yourself. After that another Mod has to undelete, unless there is a territorial issues.

Comment: If you check complete screenshot, the reason is given in the first comment itself. There is no necessity that a mod should wait till someone flags. Moreover, you don't know if someone flagged it or not. So, it is only assumption that there are no flags. A moderator can act without flags also.

Comment: Another answer was deleted because there were no references to back up even after many months. Answers without proper sources are subjected to deletion according to site policy even if it has upvotes.

Comment: If it has been flagged there was no need of moderator to put a comment @Saravabhouma

Comment: @iammilind True that.

Comment: Moderators always leave a comment before deleting an answer on the site. It is done because there is no automatic notification when the answer is deleted. Not because there are no flags on the answer. There are no "enough" flags for NAA. It will be the same if there are 10 flags or 1 flag. If there was no comment before deletion, users rant that they are not notified before deletion.

Comment: Such kindness! Much Wow! @Sarvabhouma

Comment: When a Mod's response is required then they are never found responding.. but someone else is always there to respond on their behalf.. This is something that I've been noticing over the past few months.. A new trend @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: Good observation ! @Rickross Read first comment milind posts also got deleted.

Comment: Those who are saying someone else are answering should see who deleted the answer and they will find a name beside Keshav Srinivasan. I doubt they read the answer which we are discussing!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that you have raised answer deletion issue on meta. I thought you know that answer will be deleted.

Here's the first half of the screenshot. I think that will help understand why the answer was deleted.

[image: deleted answer screenshot]

I explained that your answer is not addressing about Madhvacharya's logic about Shaktas. Your answer was explaing what Shiva Sutras say about Shakti which is not asked by the author of the question.  The answer should be given from the point of view Dvaita philosophy but you have referenced from a text which teaches non dualism. So, it is completely unrelated.

You also agreed that the answer should be addressing what Madhvacharya or his followers said about Shaktas and asked me to flag the answer as NotAn Answer.

> Of course it should be, I put an answer as counter argument. If this is not correct way, flag as not an answer. No problem :) @Sarvabhouma

Answers should not be counter argument to the question. If someone posts a question on "How does Acharya Abhinavagupta prove that there is no difference between Paramatma and Jivatma" and a user posts an argument of Madhvacharya how there is a difference between Jiva and Paramatma, that is definitely not an answer because the question asked for something and answer provides something else. In [Shog9's words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/357396), question asks for apple and you give an orange.

Moderator also gave reason why the answer is deleted.

> This doesn't answer the question, which is about what the logic of Madhvacharya's argument is, so I'm deleting your answer.

Now answering your questions one by one,

> I am sure I didn't receive enough flag for my answer

There are no enough flags for Not an answer. It will be the same if there are 10 flags or a single flag. Only spam and Rude/Abusive flags have enough flags. 6 red flags are enough to delete a post. It's not the case for NAA flags. Flags do not delete an answer, votes do. 3 delete votes from 20k users (4k on beta) or 1 delete vote from a moderator are necessary.

Moreover you don't know if users have flagged your answers or not. But in your case, there was at least one flag which put your answer in "Very Low Quality" queue. Two users gave review as "Looks OK" (Wrong reviews.. please give accurate reviews users..) but doesn't look OK according to the site rules. There are upvotes to the comments which I posted that the answer doesn't address the question. So, I assume there are other flags on the answer too.

> Why he doesn't respect SE community tools and rules? Why he is making all decisions on his own

I don't see any violation here. A moderator should be independent and take their decisions on his own. That is why there is a diamond beside their names. If not, there would be no difference between a normal newbie and a moderator. There are enough guidelines in their cheat sheet on when to delete an answer. In this case, it clearer. Easy decision. The deletion didn't happen within minutes (there are instances where moderators deleted NAA within 2 minutes before it caught normal user's attention). There was time between answering and deletion. Besides this, this moderator is also the author of the question. So, he knows whether the question is addressed or not.

> Just because he is a moderator, He should abuse his privileges ?

Other answer was deleted because there was no citations in the answer. There is no abuse of privilege here. Just a deletion of an answer which is according to site's policy.

You also said that [you would not post answers like NAA](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44207355#44207355) but had to post it. You didn't edit with valid references even when I asked you to add more than once. So, I am surprised that you had posted a meta in spite of knowing that your answer was flagged and reason of deletion was given by me before deletion and moderator (at the time of deletion).

Comment: You shouldn't have referred link of chat over here.

Comment: I also wondering why did you put refererence of Acharya Abhinavgupta to prove your point ?

Comment: Be aware, I never said, either I am Shaivaite or Vaishnavite. I don't want to be under you guys bad influence of sects. Don't judge me based on that. Avoid attacking personal argument. You were good upto your apple and orange logic. Don't go ahead of that.

Comment: @Thelittlenaruto why shouldn't I put a chat link here? You asked me to flag it when you said you know that you wrote a NAA in chat only na?  If it is not Acharya Abhinavagupta, some other Acharya question answering with another point of view. You were answering with unrelated point of view. That's my point.

Comment: Even I didn't say you are a Vaishnava or Shaiva or some other, I didn't make any personal attack or argument in the answer. I just clarified the questions you asked one by one. Following a sect is not a bad influence. It is a wrong opinion totally.

Comment: I can see what are you trying to clearify.

Comment: Good. Then edit the answer from dvaita point of view and flag for moderator attention. It will be undeleted.

Comment: If you are offended by Acharya Abhinavagupta name in the answer (I meant no offense though) , say I will edit it with other example and other name.

Comment: Well you know rules and regulations way more than me, You would know what can be offensive and what not. No need to edit. But your intentions... Anyway I came to know Keshav wrongdoing is not new. See for example this : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/21657/revisions check the first revision. I am sure according to you it'll be okay only.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I answered about present and this answer is not a wrong doing. It's a fair deletion.According to the site rules, one should not promote directly or indirectly. So, one should not add such statements.However, there are many answers and comments on the site which some philosophy is supreme and users bolding sentences that one must worship their favorite god which is unrelated to the question.People close their ears and eyes when these are brought to their notice.When one is criticized, all should be criticized. Don't blindly oppose a mod.You don't know what happened in the past.

Comment: I am Noone who is qualified enough to judge here. But such ignorance(as in being Neutral) will take you to no conclusion.