# Why aren't all NAAs treated equally on this site?

Tags: discussion, moderators, answers

The question *[Historically, when (and why) did Ganga become a holy river? Is it after Sarasvati dried up?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/285)* has two answers which are written from a purely Puranic point of view and does not address OP's question in the slightest. Despite flagging these two answers are still not deleted. No explanation was given by mods who handled the flags either in comments under the question or the two answers as to why the flags were rejected/disputed.

We have an ex-mod [clearly explaining](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/285/historically-when-and-why-did-ganga-become-a-holy-river-is-it-after-sarasvat#comment769_285) how this question should be answered.

> That is not a duplicate. OP is asking when (historically) the Ganga was deemed sacred, not why (scripturally) the Ganga is deemed sacred. – senshin Jun 22 '14 at 6:29

In the [other meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1309/2995) there was a discussion about why a particular user's post was deemed NAA (not an answer) and promptly deleted.

Why aren't all NAAs treated equally on this site?

Comment: Answers to that question should be given from Historical point of view but it was not. As far as I remember, I reviewed as Recommend deletion but others selected Looks OK. What is the use if users and reviewers add comments from reviews to correct the answer? Answerers give a deaf ear to that. Mods didn't look at it. Those should be deleted.

Comment: Do we really need the new tag? I don't think so.

Comment: No Moderator bias. Both flags were disputed.

Comment: Sarvabhouma sent me link [to this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/19106) @TheDestroyer You tell me if there's mod bias or not.

Comment: @sv. I think it's not bias. Pandya could have been thinking Puranas as history. You can ask him directly for better answer.

Comment: 'You can ask him directly for better answer' - that's what I did :) @TheDestroyer

Comment: Moderators can act irrespective of reviews also. If some users give wrong reviews, other users and mods should correct it. Going by review even though it's wrong is not a good call. Didn't mods reopen the question if some users have VTC wrongly in the past? Don't they decline wrongly raised flags on Q&A? Will the mods correct the reviews or follow wrong reviews? There is a lot of difference between History and Puranas.

Comment: Well, we [have asked clarification](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/285/historically-when-and-why-did-ganga-become-a-holy-river-is-it-after-sarasvat#comment78590_285) from OP.

Comment: @Pandya Check previous comments under the question. I thought it was pretty clear OP was looking for an answer from historical events. Not from Hindu mythology. Until the two new 'mythological' answers showed up there wasn't an issue.

Comment: @Pandya It is clear already. History is different from Puranas. The difference between history and scriptures like puranas is what that made a difference between two questions and stopped closure. Answer is needed from research work of historians and archeologists and not from Puranas. This shows a difference between a believer and non believer.